# ftp xp_cmdshell script within a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ftp, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm building a stored procedure to transfer data from SQL Server to a remote FTP server.
I wrote the table data to a file with the following query

```
exec xp_cmdshell "bcp master.dbo.table out c:\temp\bcp_outputFile.txt -S(local)\SQLEXPRESS -T -c"
```

However, I'm struggling with building a script that would take that file and send it across to the FTP Server.

Using SSIS is not an option. It must be done with the `xp_cmdshell` command.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below mention procedure for uploading the file in the ftp server.
here in the procedure i have hard coded the ftp details you can change it.

```
create procedure [dbo].[uploadfile_ftp]
    @SourcePath varchar(128),
    @SourceFiles varchar(128),
    @DestPath varchar(128)
AS
Begin

DECLARE @FTPServer varchar(128)
DECLARE @FTPUser varchar(128)
DECLARE @FTPPwd varchar(128)
DECLARE @FTPMode varchar(10)

-- FTP attributes.
SET @FTPServer = 'ftp url'
SET @FTPUser = 'ftp username'
SET @FTPPwd = 'ftp password'
SET @FTPMode = 'binary' -- ascii, binary or blank for default.

DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)
DECLARE @workfile varchar(128)
DECLARE @nowstr varchar(25)

-- Get the %TEMP% environment variable.
DECLARE @tempdir varchar(128)
CREATE TABLE #tempvartable(info VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT #tempvartable EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'echo %temp%'
SET @tempdir = (SELECT top 1 info FROM #tempvartable)
IF RIGHT(@tempdir, 1) <> '\' SET @tempdir = @tempdir + '\'
DROP TABLE #tempvartable

-- Generate @workfile
SET @nowstr = replace(replace(convert(varchar(30), GETDATE(), 121), ' ', '_'), ':', '-')
SET @workfile = 'FTP_SPID' + convert(varchar(128), @@spid) + '_' + @nowstr + '.txt'

-- Deal with special chars for echo commands.
select @FTPServer = replace(replace(replace(@FTPServer, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
select @FTPUser = replace(replace(replace(@FTPUser, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
select @FTPPwd = replace(replace(replace(@FTPPwd, '&', '^&'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
select @DestPath = replace(replace(replace(@DestPath, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
IF RIGHT(@SourcePath, 1) <> '\' SET @SourcePath = @SourcePath + '\'

-- Build the FTP script file.
select @cmd = 'echo ' + 'open ' + @FTPServer + ' > ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
print @cmd;

select @cmd = 'echo ' + @FTPUser + '>> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
print @cmd;

select @cmd = 'echo ' + @FTPPwd + '>> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
print @cmd;

select @cmd = 'echo ' + 'prompt ' + ' >> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
print @cmd;

IF LEN(@FTPMode) > 0
BEGIN
    select @cmd = 'echo ' + @FTPMode + ' >> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
END
IF LEN(@DestPath) > 0
BEGIN
    select @cmd = 'echo ' + 'cd ' + @DestPath + ' >> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
END
select @cmd = 'echo ' + 'mput ' + @SourcePath + @SourceFiles + ' >> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
select @cmd = 'echo ' + 'quit' + ' >> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

-- Execute the FTP command via script file.
select @cmd = 'ftp -s:' + @tempdir + @workfile
print @cmd;
create table #a (id int identity(1,1), s varchar(1000))
insert #a
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
select id, ouputtmp = s from #a

-- Clean up.
drop table #a
select @cmd = 'del ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

End
```